# My unity game has bugs when builded to webgl

Tags: unity-game-engine, webassembly, unity-webgl

My game has a very simple structure. It is an interactive film (like Black Mirror Bandersnatch) where you can choose between 3 scenes. By pressing 1, 2 or 3 it leads you to a new unity scene that is playing a video (URL link). 
There is also a "secret" scene that appears when you press any other button (from 4 to 9). And here is my problem:
The game is working fine on unity! It shows the right video when pressing 4-9 button. But when building the game and uploading it to my server, pressing 4-9 leads you to the wrong video (back to the loading scene instead of the "secret" scene). 
So I guess the error occurs when webassembly.
Does anyone know how to fix that problem?

Here is the link to the interactive film : [lonelyrobot.club](https://lonelyrobot.club)

And here is the script that I use in every scene:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;

public class street : MonoBehaviour
{

void Update()
{
    if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1)))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("hotel_hall");
    }
    if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2)))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("walk1");
    }
    if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha3)))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("taxi1");
    }
    if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha4)))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("lost");
    }
    if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha5)))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("lost");
    }
    if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha6)))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("lost");
    }
    if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha7)))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("lost");
    }
    if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha8)))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("lost");
    }
    if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha9)))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("lost");
    }
    if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha0)))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("lost");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is the "lost" scene added to your build settings? File->BuildSettings -> Scenes in build.

Comment: Hi Leo and thanks for your answer ! Yes it is.